# Not getting email body and attachment while sending email in background

Tags: java, android, email-attachments, email

I am trying to send email in background. Everything is working fine i am getting mail also but the problem is i am not getting email body and attachment in email.

I am not getting any error or any exception, i am getting mail also in my mail id but just the problem is attachment and email body, in attachment i am trying to send image from sdcard. So what is the problem in the following code. Can anyone help.

**GMailSender.java**

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;
    private Multipart _multipart;

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
    }

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
        _multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body,
            String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(
                body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
        message.setSubject(subject);

        message.setDataHandler(handler);
        message.setContent(_multipart);
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
        else
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(
                    recipients));
        Transport.send(message);

    }

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
        private byte[] data;
        private String type;

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getContentType() {
            if (type == null)
                return "application/octet-stream";
            else
                return type;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";
        }

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");
        }
    }
}
```

**JSSEProvider.java**

```
public class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController
                .doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
                    public Void run() {
                        put("SSLContext.TLS",
                                "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                        put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                        put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                                "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                        put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                                "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                        return null;
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

**Activity.java**

```
Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                new sendEmail().execute();
            }
        });
```

and

```
public class sendEmail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                String subject = "Registration";
                String message = "Thank you for regestering with";
                String senderOfmail = "abcd@gmail.com";
                String receiver = "abcd@gmail.com";

                GMailSender sender = new GMailSender(
                        "abcd@gmail.com", "abcde12345");
                sender.sendMail(subject, message, senderOfmail, receiver);

                FileOutputStream outStream;
                File file;
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                String extStorageDirectory = Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

                file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "ic_launcher.PNG");
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    String fileName = file.toString().trim();
                    sender.addAttachment(fileName);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this,
                            "There was a problem sending the email.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("error", e.getMessage(), e);
                return "Email Not Sent";
            }
            return "Email Sent";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are sending mail before your attachment get added to `sender`. Please add `sender.addAttachment(fileName);` before `sender.sendMail(...)`

Comment: @VikalpPatel, And what about body message. that is `String message = "Thank you for regestering with";` i am not getting this message also.